# Wrong path when trying to build Windows App project on command line with msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, windows

I am trying to use MSBuild to build a Windows 8.1 Phone and a Windows 8.1 Desktop app. 
The project contains a Shared Folder for common code and a folder each for the Phone and the Desktop App. My Computer is running Windows 10 preview with Visual Studio 2015.
When I try to build the app with the commandline via MSBuild:

```
>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild AppName.sln /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

I get errors because Windows is trying to create folders with a wrong path:

```
Creating directory "bin\Debug\C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\....".
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried to specify the output path? C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild AppName.sln /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0,OutDir=Valid/Path/Goes/Here

Comment: Missing either the outdir or outputpath parameter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464350/output-path-and-msbuild

Comment: Thanks, the missing outdir was the reason. If you create an  answer I can reward you with the bounty

Answer (score 4):

change the `<OutputPath></OutputPath>`

You can find explanation about the tag in [Visual Studio Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6db0hwky.aspx)

So, for example, the C# Console Application template is located in

```
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ConsoleApplication\consoleapplication.csproj
```

The csproj is an XML file that you can edit at your will. The build output directory is define like this (for each configuration):

```
...
<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
...
<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
...
```

If you change this file, it will change all your future new C# Console Application projects.

Comment: I tried that, however it did not change the initial issue